# C++ Game-engine: Cache-friendly gameObject design

Tags: c++, performance, caching, game-engine, data-oriented-design

I'm currently working on the development of an Game-engine in C++ and so forth I designed my gameObject this way:

Each data component are allocated contiguously in memory, and are pushed in the pipeline they belongs to. At runtime, each module compute the list of data-component they have.

Data:

Ai Ai Ai

Render Render Render

Physics Physics Physics

```
foreach ai in AI
   computeAI(ai);
foreach render in Render
   computeRender(render);
foreach physics in Physics
   computePhysics(physics);
```

The problem is: what if they are data-component that are used by several modules ? The position of the entity for example. Is is lethal to the cache line to load them in each module ?

Have you got some suggestion to improve such a design ? Or should I use another one ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: separate the concerns of storage strategy and game logic. Then write the game. If it runs too slowly (it won't) you can revisit the storage component with a view to finding bottlenecks.
Players care about playing, not about implementation detail. At this stage so should you.

Comment: Idd. But the cache-friendliness and speed is the what I want to learn from this pedagogical project. It must be has fast as possible, no matter the time it takes.

Comment: having separated concerns, you can then easily write a number of different variations of storage strategies. Then you can time them, against the same logic.
It really is the only way. The combination of compiler, optimiser, cpu caches, memory caches and hardware architecture will do surprising things that you (and anyone else) cannot easily predict.

Comment: google "Data driven design" and abandon object concept if you want true cache friendliness. However it may put severe requirements on skill.

Comment: @VladimirS Its "Data-orientated Design", not "driven" :)

Comment: @roug Look for the Sony presentation slides on data-orientated design.

Comment: http://www.dice.se/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/Introduction_to_Data-Oriented_Design.pdf

Comment: I don't quite follow. What do you mean by modules? There isn't cache contention across dylibs, e.g., running in the same thread.